# Python pandas object converts column names with special characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv, special-characters

I have a pandas dataframe structured like:

```
>>> df
   Col1  Col.With.Dots  Col.With.#  Col.With.%
0  text            111         111         111
1  text            222         222         222
2  text            333         333         333
3  text            444         444         444
4  text            555         555         555
```

When iterating over it with `itertuples()`, the columns with **special characters** break:

```
>>> for i in df.itertuples():
...    print i

Pandas(Index=0, Col1='text', _2=111, _3=111, _4=111)
Pandas(Index=1, Col1='text', _2=222, _3=222, _4=222)
Pandas(Index=2, Col1='text', _2=333, _3=333, _4=333)
Pandas(Index=3, Col1='text', _2=444, _3=444, _4=444)
Pandas(Index=4, Col1='text', _2=555, _3=555, _4=555)
```

"_2", "_3", "_4" should be "Col.With.Dots", "Col.With.#", "Col.With.%" in the print output, respectively.

I need to convert the **dataframe** object to a **raw dict**. So every pandas object is changed to a dict such:
`{'Col1': 'text', 'Col.With.Dots': 111, 'Col.With.#': 111, 'Col.With.%': 111 }`

Is there a way to overcome this? I did some research and couldn't find an answer

Comment: They are not _broken_, they are _fixed_. `Col.With.Dots` and the like are no valid Python identifiers. Pandas is doing its best to avoid them.

Comment: @DYZ I understand that, but I need to convert this structure to a raw dict

Comment: Why not rename the columns?

Comment: @JohnGalt converting the dataframe to a rawdict (list of dicts), so for every pandas object I get a dict {'Col1': 'text', 'Col.With.Dots': 111, 'Col.With.#': 111...

Comment: @Asterisk this is part of a larger program, and I'm trying to avoid modifying the headers. This works fine using the `csv` module, however when the csv size gets large (500mb+) it fails where pandas successfully loads the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

```
In [1659]: df.to_dict('r')
Out[1659]:
[{'Col.With.#': 111L, 'Col.With.%': 111L, 'Col.With.Dots': 111L, 'Col1': 'text'},
 {'Col.With.#': 222L, 'Col.With.%': 222L, 'Col.With.Dots': 222L, 'Col1': 'text'},
 {'Col.With.#': 333L, 'Col.With.%': 333L, 'Col.With.Dots': 333L, 'Col1': 'text'},
 {'Col.With.#': 444L, 'Col.With.%': 444L, 'Col.With.Dots': 444L, 'Col1': 'text'},
 {'Col.With.#': 555L, 'Col.With.%': 555L, 'Col.With.Dots': 555L, 'Col1': 'text'}]
```

Or, for looping, use [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) with `to_dict()`

```
In [1667]: for i, x in df.iterrows():
      ...:     print x.to_dict()
      ...:
{'Col.With.%': 111L, 'Col.With.Dots': 111L, 'Col.With.#': 111L, 'Col1': 'text'}
{'Col.With.%': 222L, 'Col.With.Dots': 222L, 'Col.With.#': 222L, 'Col1': 'text'}
{'Col.With.%': 333L, 'Col.With.Dots': 333L, 'Col.With.#': 333L, 'Col1': 'text'}
{'Col.With.%': 444L, 'Col.With.Dots': 444L, 'Col.With.#': 444L, 'Col1': 'text'}
{'Col.With.%': 555L, 'Col.With.Dots': 555L, 'Col.With.#': 555L, 'Col1': 'text'}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. btw - is there a way to change the values from float to int before converting?